# I use many languages, but speak only one. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am not blind
>   I am not dull
>   I use many languages
>   but speak only one.

***What am I?***

Comment: *`I learnt from many languages`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The answer is

> **C#** (programming language)

I am not blind, I am not dull

> Not blind = **see (C)**; not dull = **sharp**

I use many languages

> C# was developed on the backs of several different languages, and borrows concepts from several of them (Java, C/C++, others...?)

But speak only one

> Itself it is just one language: C#

Comment: He should have said `I learnt from many languages`.

Comment: Whoa, what a brilliant answer :D

Comment: @gsamaras nah, "I know many languages, but speak only one" would have worked better.

Answer (score 29):

Are you

> A computer

I am not blind

> webcams on a computer can see

I am not dull

> Computers are able to perform many calculations and thus aren't dull

I use many languages

> Most computers use many programming languages

but speak only one

> But all the languages need to be reduced to binary for the computer to handle.

Comment: Nope! but a good guess nonetheless!

Comment: @Alex Rohr Is he any close? Because I was thinking somewhat along the same lines...

Comment: @Sid it is the right general direction

Comment: And with the recent introduction of quantum computing, binary is no longer the only language computers can speak

Comment: @Areeb good point but I would argue that  quantum computers are almost always referred to explicitly as "quantum".  So a "computer" would generally be regarded as a classic (non-quantum) computer.

Comment: @gtwebb Yeah I don't see commercial quantum computers coming anytime soon, so the current connotation is going to stick

Comment: Binary is not a language, just as decimal isn't.

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich Binary is an alphabet, for which we have machine instructions as the language.

Comment: The language a computer directly executes is, aptly, named "machine language". That it is stored in binary form is just because on our computers *everything* is stored in binary form. On a ternary computer, the machine language would be ternary. And a quantum computer would probably have a quantum machine language.

Comment: Or you can say the one language is assembly.

Comment: Computers absolutely are dull.  They only do what they are told.  And if they're not told anything, they do nothing.

Comment: @Nemo Assembly is a human-readable version of machine language that uses mnemonics for the opcodes.  Assembly can be translated to machine code with an assembler, but the computer does not execute assembly directly.

Comment: @NobodyNada if there is an [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) between the two, it's the same. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I know what you are.

> A programmer.

because

> Uses many programming languages but speaks only English.
>   Is not dull but rather very smart
>   and can see because needs to see to program.

Comment: does not need to see to program, at work we have a blind programmer on our staff, he uses a screen reader when operating the computer, and a cane when traveling.

Comment: A programmer can be a polyglot. So the last condition is not always met.

Comment: Can I merge this account with my real one?

Comment: And many of my programmer colleagues are rather dull...

Comment: @Highstalker: Then a monoglot programmer.

Answer (score 7):

What are you?

> You are mute.

I am not blind
I am not dull

> Your senses and intellect are fine, you just lack the ability to speak vocally.

I use many languages
but speak only one.

> No matter which languages you use, they are all "spoken" in sign language.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Computer programmer?

This answer satisfies the conditions...

> They aren't blind (need to see the computer) or dull (programming is fun!), and they use very many (coding) languages, but they might only be monolingual in the real world.

Answer (score -1):

> I think it's a translation robot or algorithm like translate.google.com

I am not blind

> I see many people who visit me

I am not dull

> translation is fun

I use many languages

> upwards of 50 languages

but speak only one.

> the language I am programmed in.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please [use >! for adding spoilers](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) so that others (who are currently solving the same puzzle) don't see your answer :)

Comment: it didn't work when i corrected but now all of a sudden it does. plse remove the minus one

Comment: I've formatted it for you, please [refer to this link](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-to-format-text-inside-spoilers). No, I didn't downvote O:)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

- I am not blind (yes I am not)
- I am not dull (yes I am not)
- I use many languages (currently 3)
- But speak only one (on the others I only try)

So I am:

> A common foreigner in Germany! :-)

:-) Sorry for the joke, I am also one of them. :-)

Comment: (no prob, delete it)